# GET request variable error in PHP

Tags: php

I have a simple PHP code, as below.

When I try the URL `localhost/df.php?result1=bharat`, I get the result `Bharat`, exactly as I want it. But when I try the URL `localhost/df.php?result2=bharat`, I get an error, meaning my `result2` variable was not read like my `result1` variable did.

Could you please correct my code so that it works?

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['Result1']))
{
    $file = $_GET['Result1'];
}
else
{
    echo "Error"; exit; 
}
echo "$result1";
?>
elseif(isset($_GET['Result2']))
{
    $file = $_GET['Result2'];
}
else
{
    echo "Error"; exit; 
}
echo "$result2";
?>
```

Comment: Your `if` construct is broken. You have two `else`s for one `if`.

Comment: your php code has syntax errors, please start by having start and end tags and a correct `if` structure.

Comment: Please answer The Proper code where i have to add if

Comment: @HackerzcityWrest - SO is not here to teach you how to write php. If you don't know how `if(){}else{}` are suppose to be build, I recommend you find a php tutorial and learn.

Answer (score 2):

You have **way too many errors** in your code. The following is the solution to your problem:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['result1']))
{
    $result1 = $_GET['result1'];
    echo $result1;
}
elseif(isset($_GET['result2']))
{
    $result2 = $_GET['result2'];
    echo $result2;
}
else
{
    echo "Error";
    exit(); 
}
?>
```

> For the future, I would recommend you to learn PHP and be familiar with the basic syntax, **at least**, before posting questions about it here.

Comment: bro localhost/df.php?result2=bharat  Get result nothing

Comment: I made a small typo there. The variable inside `elseif` needs to be `$result2`, not `$result`. Let me update the code!

Comment: Cheers! Remember to upvote and accept the answer if it works for you. :)